# Second fundamental form

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

How do I calculate the integral of the trace of the [second fundamental form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) on a surface?

The formula used in the Gibbons, Hawking, York paper *Action integrals and partition functions in quantum gravity,* how do I derive it? Is it a universal or does it have any assumptions about the kind of space time we are considering?

The formula is,
$$\int K d\Sigma = \frac{\partial}{\partial n}\int d\Sigma$$

$K$ is the trace of the second fundamental form, $d\Sigma$ is the area element and the derivative is along the outward normal to the surface.

Answer (score 2):

The boundary term of the Einstein-Hilbert action is given by,

$$S= \frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_{\partial M} \! \!\mathrm{d}^3x \, \sqrt{-h} \, K$$

where $h$ is the metric on the boundary of the manifold, i.e. $\partial M$, and $K$ is the trace of the extrinsic curvature. Specifically, we have,

$$K=\nabla_a n^a$$

where $n^a$ is a unit normal to the surface $\partial M$. The derivation follows by applying the Gauss-Codazzi formalism of differential geometry. Recall the variation of the Einstein-Hilbert action is,

$$\delta S_{EH}=-\frac{1}{16\pi G} \int_M \mathrm{d}^4x \, \sqrt{g} \, \delta g^{ab}G_{ab}-\frac{1}{16\pi G}\int_{\partial M} \mathrm{d}^3 x \, \sqrt{g} \left( \nabla_n \delta g -n_a\nabla_b g^{ab} \right)$$

The boundary is a submanifold, and a natural curvature scalar to select, rather than $R$, is the extrinsic curvature; the variation of $K$ is given by,

$$\delta K = \delta (\nabla_a n^a)=\nabla_a \delta n^a + \delta \Gamma^a_{ab}n^b$$

With some manipulation, which is found in virtually any general relativity textbook, it can be shown that the addition directly cancels the variation of the Einstein-Hilbert action, up to total derivatives.

---

As a practical example, consider the metric,

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \left( 1- \frac{2GM}{r}\right)\mathrm{d}\tau^2 + \left( 1-\frac{2GM}{r} \right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta \mathrm{d}\phi^2$$

which is simply a Wick rotated Schwarzschild black hole, with periodic $\tau$ with period $\beta$. We may choose an inward pointing normal, correctly normalized such that $n_an^a = 1$, given by,

$$n^{a} = - \sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r}}\delta^a_r$$

Taking the divergence of the normal, we obtain,

$$K= -\left( 1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1/2} \left( \frac{2}{r}-\frac{3GM}{r^2}\right)$$

The action is divergent, unless we introduce a radial cut-off, $R$. Note also we pick up a factor of $r^2$ from the determinant of the metric in the action; we find,

$$-8\pi G \, S= \int \mathrm{d}\tau \, \mathrm{d}\phi \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \left( 2R -3GMR\right)=4\pi \beta \left( 2R -3GMR\right)$$

To regularize the integral, we must subtract off the contribution from flat space, with the same boundary.

Comment: So, does the formula that I wrote in the question apply irrespective of the kind of space time I have ?

Do you know of any situation where the Gibbons Hawking York correction term needs modification, for say a space time with corners (like a cylinder) or otherwise ?

Comment: @Sourav: No, the boundary term should always stay the same, unless you introduce additional fields. However, often it requires some form of regularization. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0017; they compute the action for a particular solution which had conical singularities, and they demonstrated how to deal with those.

Comment: please look at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.2919v2.pdf , equation 12. They have an extra factor of half with the GHY boundary term.

Comment: @Sourav: If you check [40] in the references, you'll see they state they need to take a half of the boundary term due to the flat space boundary conditons [9,10]. Also, regarding modifications to the boundary term, see the works of Hawking on arXiv; he shows some explicit cases.

Comment: I am sorry I am missing something, but Schwarzschild is also asymptotically flat, so why are we not considering the extra half there ?